# Is there a way to prevent email detection with javascript

Tags: javascript, email, detect

I'm going to try to describe this the best I can. I have a form that the user fills out, when it confirms the users info, it then prints it out on a table, and the user may edit it directly on the table using the contendEditable attribute. The problem i'm having is if the user edits his/her email address, the browser detects it as an email address (since it's not in an input element) and doesn't pass the email through the form. All other values go through fine. I'm using PHP to process the form and just print out the fields to make sure it goes through properly.

The confirm page should like this:

```
John,Smith,JSMITH,abc@123.com,111-222-3345
```

But it looks like this:

```
John,Smith,JSMITH,null,111-222-3345
```

Any suggestions?

It would be easier if i posted my code so here it is:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "ext.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name = "setupForm" id = "setupForm" action = "confirmSetup.php" method = "post">
      <div id = "confirmInfo"></div>
      <div id = "hiddenFields"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

/* I didn't put my full code on here as it is way too long.
   But this HTML document is what is shown after input fields 
   have been previously submit, and this page is just to confirm 
   the user input.
*/
```

JS:

```
function verifyInfo(){ // This function is called when user submits all his info
  var firstname = document.getElementById("txtFirstname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("txtLastname").value;
  var username = document.getElementById("hdnUsername").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("txtPhone").value;
  var output = "";
  output += "<table id = 'confirm'>";
  output += "<tr>";
  output += "  <th>Firstname</th>";
  output += "  <td id = 'tdFirstname'>";
  output += "    <div onkeyup = 'updateUsername()' contentEditable>" + firstname + "</div>";
  output += "  </td>";
  output += "</tr>";
  output += "<tr>";
  output += "  <th>Lastname</th>";
  output += "  <td id = 'tdLastname'>";
  output += "    <div onkeyup = 'updateUsername()' contentEditable>" + lastname + "</div>";
  output += "  </td>";
  output += "</tr>";
  output += "<tr>";
  output += "  <th>Username</th>";
  output += "  <td id = 'tdUsername'>" + username + "</td>";
  output += "</tr>";
  output += "<tr>";
  output += "  <th>Email</th>";
  output += "  <td id = 'tdEmail'>";
  output += "    <div style = 'min-width:1px;' onkeyup = 'verifyEmail(this.parentNode.id,event)' contentEditable>" + email + "</div>";
  output += "    <div id = 'validInvalid'>";
  output += "      <span class = 'dgreen'><br/>Valid email!</span>";
  output += "    </div>";
  output += "  </td>";
  output += "</tr>";
  output += "<tr>";
  output += "  <th>Phone</th>";
  output += "  <td id = 'tdPhone'>";
  output += "    <div style = 'min-width:1px;' onkeyup = 'verifyPhone(this.parentNode.id,event)' contentEditable>" + phone + "</div>";
  output += "    <div id = 'validInvalid1'>";
  output += "      <span class = 'dgreen'><br/>Valid phone!</span>";
  output += "    </div>";
  output += "  </td>";
  output += "</tr>";
  output += "</table>";
  output += "<input type = 'button' name = 'submitSetup' id = 'submitSetup' value = 'Get Set Up!' onclick = 'goToConfirm()'/>";
  document.getElementById("confirmInfo").innerHTML = output;
}

/* The way that function works is it takes the inputted text,
   and places it into the table. This table enables the user to dynamically make any
  changes necessary right onto the table. The username is created from first initial
  and last name, which is called on the 'updateUsername()' function, which I am leaving
  out.
*/

function verifyEmail(id,e){
  var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  if((unicode < 37 || unicode > 40) && unicode != 9){ // This doesn't allow email to be verified if the arrow keys, or tab key is pressed
    var email = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var emailFilter = /^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.]A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/;
    if(!emailFilter.test(email)){ // Checks if valid email
      document.getElementById("validInvalid").innerHTML = "<span class = 'red'><br/>Not a valid email!</span>";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("validInvalid").innerHTML = "<span class = 'dgree'><br/>Valid email!</span>";
    }
  }
  disableButton(); //If email or phone is invalid, button will be disabled
}

function verifyPhone(id,e){
  var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keycode;
  if((unicode < 37 || unicode > 40) && unicode != 9)){
    var phone = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
    if(phone.length > 12){ // Doesn't let user put it more than 12 characters (xxx-xxx-xxxx)
      var difference = phone.length - 12;
      phone = phone.substr(0,phone.length - difference);
      document.getElementById(id).firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue = phone;
    }
    var phoneFilter = /\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}/;
    if(!phoneFilter.test(phone)){ // Checks for valid phone number
      document.getElementById("validInvalid1").innerHTML = "<span class = 'red'><br/>Not a valid phone!</span>";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("validInvalid1").innerHTML = "<span class = 'dgreen'><br/>Valid phone!</span>";
    }
  }
  disableButton();
}

function disableButton(){
  var email = document.getElementById("tdEmail").firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.className;
  var phone = document.getElementById("tdPhone").firstChild.nextSibling.firstsChild.className;
  if(email == "red" || phone == "red"){
    document.getElementById("submitSetup").disabled = true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("submitSetup").disabled = false;
  }
}

function goToConfirm(){ //This is the function that goes to confirmsetup.php. it works fine if email isn't edited in table, but if email is edited, it doesn't work
  var firstname = document.getElementById("tdFirstname").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("tdLastname").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var username = document.getElementById("tdUsername").firstChild.nodeValue;
  var email = document.getElementById("tdEmail").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var phone = document.getElementById("tdPhone").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var hiddenfields = document.getElementById("hiddenFields");
  var input = "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hdnFirstname' id = 'hdnFirstname' value = '"+firstname+"'/>";
     input += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hdnLastname' id = 'hdnLastname' value = '"+lastname+"'/>";
     input += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hdnUsername' id = 'hdnUsername' value = '"+username+"'/>";
     input += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hdnEmail' id = 'hdnEmail' value = '"+email+"'/>";
     input += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hdnPHone' id = 'hdnPhone' value = '"+phone+"'/>";
  hiddenFields.innerHTML = input;
  document.setupForm.submit();
}

/* That is the end of my javascript file, it's a lot,
   but hopefully you can understand it
*/
```

Finally, the final php script is simple:

```
<?php

$fn = $_POST['hdnFirstname'];
$ln = $_POST['hdnLastname'];
$un = $_POST['hdnUsername'];
$em = $_POST['hdnEmail'];
$ph = $_POST['hdnPhone'];

die($fn.",".$ln.",".$un.",".$em.",".$ph);

?>
```

the firstname, lastname, username, and phone alway print out correctly.
When the email is not edited, it prints out correctly,
When the email is edited, it prints out as null.

Comment: can you submit your code?

Comment: `the browser detects it as an email address`? Since when browser decide to filter out things for the user? There is no reason why a phone number should work, where an email address should be filtered out by the browser.

Comment: Did you check if your email textbox has "name" attribute in it?

Comment: There's not code to see... Maybe you should submit the `innerText/textContent` instead of `innerHTML`?

Comment: Code submitted, took some time, but I got it up.

Comment: @gaurav It does have a name attribute. The only time it doesn't work, is if the user edits the email in the table.

Comment: Ok so I went through all your code and think that its only the email's value the code is not able to fetch somehow. Have you tried to alert email value after you set var email = document.getElementById("tdEmail").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue; ?

Comment: Yes. It comes up as null. It only happens after i edit the email and then the browser (IE) turns it blue and underlines it as an email link.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect, values are parsed as text. Please review the code and make sure that you parse correct form names from http request object. It should fix your issue.

Comment: The code works fine if the user doesn't edit the email. But once the user edits it, it's 50/50 on whether it works or not.